# Does the restoration of system affect previous versions of files/folders

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, previous-versions

I have a small dilemma: let's assume that I have a folder which last previous version is dated 27th January and my last system restoration point had been created before the day, let's say 25th January. Question is: if I restored my system to 25th January, would I lose the previous version of the mentioned folder (27th Jan)?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What sort of System Restore? Where is the folder located in the file system? Generally, system restores ONLY affect OS and some application content and do not reset all files or folders back to that date.

Comment: I mean restoration via System Restore Point and a non-executable file stored in the Documents folder (system partition). I know that system restore affects only OS and some applications, but my question is: Do the restoration of the system affects the possibility of restoring a previous version of such a file. The essential part of dilemma is the fact that the system restore point was created earlier than the last previous version of the file. It's a bit twisted - I know - hope I can get my point across :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** System Restore and Previous Versions work independently of each other. While they both leverage the same Volume Snapshot (VSS) technology to achieve their functionality, reverting a system's state to a prior Restore Point does not remove any snapshots (a.k.a. Shadow Copies, a.k.a. Previous Versions) that may be available for the volume.

One possible exception would be if you are low on disk space or if the shadow copy storage space allocated for Previous Versions is near it's limit. While I haven't witnessed this, it's possible that running a System Restore operation could temporarily consume enough disk space to trigger deletion of one or more of the shadow copies used to store the Previous Versions. **When in doubt, always have backups of important files before attempting operations that could lead to data loss.**

That said, you may be over-estimating the finality of a System Restore operation. They only affect files deemed part of the system's "configuration" (e.g. the Registry, contents of critical system folders and program files, etc.) but leave all other files unchanged. Further, they are completely reversible; you can actually *undo* a restore operation and return the system to the original (chronologically most recent) configuration as easily as you can revert to an older restore point.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Windows System Restore is not a file backup utility. It is an OS repair function.

System Restore does not backup data files. It saves the state of the OS and certain application files and settings, and allows these to be restored.

Contents of your My Documents directory are not affected by System Restore.